# How To Apply Conditions In A DataFrame To Give A Particular Set Of Value Or Values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have here two questions that I can't find a solution to. Pls, help.[image]

This is a python pandas DataFrame and not a MySQL table. For the first question here is the code that I tried:

```
for x in stock["Price"]:
    if x < 150:
            print(stock[["ItemNo","ItemName"]])
    else:
            print("Error")
```

"stock" is the name of the DataFrame that I used.

Comment: What is output of `ii` ?

Comment: The output should come for all the details for both tea and green tea

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Meaning all the values under tea and green tea.

Comment: Super, please check link above and change your question, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
# Display item number and name whose price is less than 150
less_than_150 = stock.loc[stock["price"] < 150, ["ItemNo", "ItemName"]]
print(less_than_150)

# Display detail of different types of Tea available in Shop
different_teas = stock[stock["ItemName"].str.contains("Tea", regex=False)].unique()
print(different_teas)
```